# Mounted Octopress on my Rails app but GET request is not rendered?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, octopress

Both my rails app and Octopress app work individually but when i mount my octopuses blog on my rails app the get request is never rendered.

```
       Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-12-25 06:49:54 -0500
       Processing by HomepageController#index as HTML
       Rendered homepage/index.html within layouts/application (6.4ms)
       Completed 200 OK in 929ms (Views: 892.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)




       Started GET "/blog/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-12-25 06:50:00 -0500`
```

The rails app GET request is rendered as expect.
My routes.rb file correct routes all the request to the Blog class but nothing is rendered.

**`octopress/config.ru`**

```
    require 'bundler/setup'
    require 'sinatra/base'

    # The project root directory
    $root = ::File.dirname(__FILE__)

    class Blog < Sinatra::Base

       get(/.+/) do
          send_sinatra_file(request.path) {404}
       end

        not_found do
          send_file(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'public', '404.html'),         {:status => 404})
        end

        def send_sinatra_file(path, &missing_file_block)
          file_path = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'public',  path)
          file_path = File.join(file_path, 'index.html') unless file_path =~ /\.[a-z]+$/i
           File.exist?(file_path) ? send_file(file_path) : missing_file_block.call
        end


    end
```

Comment: What does 'nothing is rendered' mean? An HTTP 200 response with an empty body? Another response? An error?

Comment: There is no error message it just hangs after the `Started GET "/blog/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-12-25 06:50:00 -0500` . On the frontend side, there is just a blank page. Seems like there is no response to the GET request.